# escape element in a list when it return Error

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler

In order to get  better skills I'am making this scripte so it takes a list of website and create a dict and take every website and crawle it to find the "conatct-us" page, But I see that my script stops when one of the websites is not working so what I am trying to do is to escape that website and continue to the others 
here's my code :

```
import  requests
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urlparse
from mechanize import Browser
import re
headers = [('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0')]

urls = 'http://www.officialusa.com/stateguides/chambers/georgia.html'
links_dict = []



response = requests.get(urls, headers)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
for tag in bsObj.find_all('li'):
       links_dict.append(tag.a.get('href'))


for ink in links_dict:
                r = requests.get(ink)
                #get domain name only
                parsed_uri = urlparse(ink)
                domain = parsed_uri.netloc
                br = Browser()
                br.set_handle_robots(False)
                br.addheaders = headers
                try:
                    br.open(str(ink))
                    for link in br.links():
                            siteMatch = re.compile(ink).search(link.url)
                            print link.url
                except:
                    pass
```

Everything is okey with the other links
here's the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qunix/PycharmProjects/challange/crawel.py", line 20, in <module>
    r = requests.get(ink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.quitmangeorgia.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7facf68cca50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
```

thank You !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the line

```
r = requests.get(ink)
```

in a try catch like so:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(ink)
except ConnectionError:
    continue
```

This will mean that if the call to `requests.get` throws a ConnectionError as it does in your example, it will pass over to the next website in the list.

Comment: thanks , finally it worked . just a small Edit  I used 
      requests.ConnectionError:

Comment: @AmineAmhoume No problem at all, I didn't have an editor open to check if you had to fully qualify the error or not but glad you solved it